# Unable to run TestScripts on safari browser on iOS devices[iOS 8] using appium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, appium

I am not able to run TestScripts on safari browser on iOS devices[iOS 8].

```
Appium version: 1.3.1
Xcode: xcode 6.0
iOS SDK: 8.0
ipad device ios version: 8.0
Installed ios-web-kit proxy
Installed SafariLauncherApp in devices.

But could`t succeed. Please help me to resolve this. I am blocked.

Appium logs:

Welcome to Appium v1.3.1 (REV 1160ce02bb89c354cb99317985123acf39f0e7d3)
info: Appium REST http interface listener started on 0.0.0.0:4723
info: Console LogLevel: debug
info: --> POST /wd/hub/session {"desiredCapabilities":{"safariIgnoreFraudWarning":"true","app":"SafariLauncher.app","platformName":"iOS","deviceName":"iPad","browserName":"iOS","safariAllowPopups":false,"udid":"b331d45d209fd3b2e118fbfd68965c5f7e472b49","version":"8.0"}}
info: Client User-Agent string: undefined
warn: Converting cap safariIgnoreFraudWarning from string to boolean. This might cause unexpected behavior.
info: [debug] The following desired capabilities were provided, but not recognized by appium. They will be passed on to any other services running on this server. : version
info: [debug] App is an iOS bundle, will attempt to run as pre-existing
info: [debug] Creating new appium session 12c663a4-5b60-4998-baee-ffa78bd80a09
info: [debug] Removing any remaining instruments sockets
info: [debug] Cleaned up instruments socket /tmp/instruments_sock
info: [debug] Setting Xcode folder
info: [debug] Setting Xcode version
info: [debug] Setting iOS SDK Version
info: [debug] Getting sdk version from xcrun with a timeout
info: [debug] iOS SDK Version set to 8.0
info: [debug] Not checking whether simulator is available since we're on a real device
info: [debug] Detecting automation tracetemplate
info: [debug] Not auto-detecting udid, running on sim
info: [debug] Could not parse plist file (as binary) at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/SafariLauncher.app/en.lproj/Localizable.strings
info: Will try to parse the plist file as XML
parseFileSync() is deprecated. Use parseStringSync() instead.
info: [debug] Could not parse plist file (as XML) at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/SafariLauncher.app/en.lproj/Localizable.strings
warn: Could not parse app Localizable.strings; assuming it doesn't exist
info: [debug] Creating instruments
info: On some xcode 6 platforms, instruments-without-delay does not work. If you experience this, you will need to re-run appium with the --native-instruments-lib flag
info: [debug] Preparing uiauto bootstrap
info: [debug] Dynamic bootstrap dir: /Users/valtech/Library/Application Support/appium/bootstrap
info: [debug] Dynamic env: {"nodePath":"/usr/local/bin/node","commandProxyClientPath":"/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-uiauto/bin/command-proxy-client.js","instrumentsSock":"/tmp/instruments_sock","interKeyDelay":null,"justLoopInfinitely":false,"autoAcceptAlerts":false}
info: [debug] Dynamic bootstrap code: // This file is automatically generated. Do not manually mod...!
info: [debug] Dynamic bootstrap path: /Users/valtech/Library/Application Support/appium/bootstrap/bootstrap-596362050ad3c71e.js
info: [debug] Reusing dynamic bootstrap: /Users/valtech/Library/Application Support/appium/bootstrap/bootstrap-596362050ad3c71e.js
info: [debug] Getting device string from opts: {"forceIphone":false,"forceIpad":false,"xcodeVersion":"6.0","iOSSDKVersion":"8.0","deviceName":"iPad","platformVersion":null}
info: [debug] fixDevice is on
info: [debug] Final device string is: 'iPad (8.0 Simulator)'
info: [debug] Not setting device type since we're on a real device
info: [debug] Checking whether we need to set app preferences
info: [debug] Not setting iOS and app preferences since we're on a real device
info: [debug] Running ios sim reset flow
info: [debug] Killing the simulator process
info: [debug] Killall iOS Simulator
info: [debug] Killing any other simulator daemons
info: [debug] On a real device; cannot clean device state
info: [debug] Not setting locale because we're using a real device
info: [debug] No iOS / app preferences to set
info: [debug] Starting iOS device log capture via deviceconsole
info: [debug] Not pre-launching simulator
info: [debug] Creating iDevice object with udid b331d45d209fd3b2e118fbfd68965c5f7e472b49
info: [debug] Couldn't find ideviceinstaller, trying built-in at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/build/libimobiledevice-macosx/ideviceinstaller
info: [debug] Checking app install status using: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/build/fruitstrap/fruitstrap isInstalled --id b331d45d209fd3b2e118fbfd68965c5f7e472b49 --bundle SafariLauncher.app
info: [debug] App is not installed. Will try to install the app.
info: [debug] Installing app using cmd: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/build/fruitstrap/fruitstrap install --id b331d45d209fd3b2e118fbfd68965c5f7e472b49 --bundle "SafariLauncher.app"
info: [debug] Cleaning up appium session
error: Failed to start an Appium session, err was: Error: Unable to install [SafariLauncher.app] to device with id [b331d45d209fd3b2e118fbfd68965c5f7e472b49]. Error [Error: Command failed: Assertion failed: (access(app_path, F_OK) == 0), function main, file fruitstrap.c, line 718.
]
info: [debug] Error: Unable to install [SafariLauncher.app] to device with id [b331d45d209fd3b2e118fbfd68965c5f7e472b49]. Error [Error: Command failed: Assertion failed: (access(app_path, F_OK) == 0), function main, file fruitstrap.c, line 718.
]
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/lib/devices/common.js:147:10
at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:641:7)
at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
at maybeClose (child_process.js:743:16)
at Socket. (child_process.js:956:11)
at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
at Pipe.close (net.js:466:12)
info: [debug] Responding to client with error: {"status":33,"value":{"message":"A new session could not be created. (Original error: Unable to install [SafariLauncher.app] to device with id [b331d45d209fd3b2e118fbfd68965c5f7e472b49]. Error [Error: Command failed: Assertion failed: (access(app_path, F_OK) == 0), function main, file fruitstrap.c, line 718.\n])","origValue":"Unable to install [SafariLauncher.app] to device with id [b331d45d209fd3b2e118fbfd68965c5f7e472b49]. Error [Error: Command failed: Assertion failed: (access(app_path, F_OK) == 0), function main, file fruitstrap.c, line 718.\n]"},"sessionId":null}
info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session 500 3527.806 ms - 574
```

ios-web-kit-proxy console:

Connected :9227 to iPad (b331d45d209fd3b2e118fbfd68965c5f7e472b49)
Invalid message rpcapplicationUpdated: 
WIRApplicationBundleIdentifierKey
com.apple.mobilesafari
WIRApplicationNameKey
Safari
WIRIsApplicationProxyKey
WIRIsApplicationActiveKey
0
WIRApplicationIdentifierKey
PID:245
Disconnected :9227 from iPad (b331d45d209fd3b2e118fbfd68965c5f7e472b49)

Thanks,
Rashmi